# A C example about using PTRACE_GETSIGMASK and PTRACE_SETSIGMASK?

Tags: ptrace

Is there a C example about using PTRACE_GETSIGMASK and PTRACE_SETSIGMASK?

I have not found any C example about using `PTRACE_GETSIGMASK/PTRACE_SETSIGMASK`, I wrote a simple code to test them, but it returns and `EINVAL error`.
I  am trying to modify the trace signal mask

Comment: Paste your code so we can help you

Answer (score -1):

kernel sizeof(sigset_t)=8, userspace sizeof(sigset_t)=128. try addr=8